# How to pass 'this' from ClassA to ClassB?

Tags: javascript, class, flutter, dart

I am trying to create a global class with multiple modules inside it. I am rewriting the code from Javascript to Dart.

**Javascript**

```
import ModuleA from './modules/a'
import ModuleB from './modules/b'
import ModuleC from './modules/c'

class Parent {
  constructor() {
    this.moduleA = new ModuleA(this)
    this.moduleB = new ModuleB(this)
    this.moduleC = new ModuleC(this)
  }
}
```

**Dart**

```dart
import 'modules/a.dart';
import 'modules/b.dart';
import 'modules/c.dart';

class Parent {
  ModuleA moduleA = ModuleA(parent: Parent());
  ModuleB moduleB = ModuleB(parent: Parent());
  ModuleC moduleC = ModuleC(parent: Parent());
}
```

After build I get this error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: Stack Overflow
```

Comment: Are you sure the JS code is correct? There's no `this` outside methods. Maybe that code should be in the contructor?

Comment: In the Dart code, you seem to be calling the Parent constructor from the Parent constructor, so you get infinite recursion.

Comment: Your Dart code doesn't actually try to pass `this` to the other classes' constructor.s  It constructs new `Parent` objects.

Comment: @jamesdlin do you know how to pass `this` instead of creating a new instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Dart class should have a constructor that initializes the members and passes `this` when constructing the members:

```dart
import 'modules/a.dart';
import 'modules/b.dart';
import 'modules/c.dart';

class Parent {
  Parent() {
    moduleA = ModuleA(parent: this);
    moduleB = ModuleB(parent: this);
    moduleC = ModuleC(parent: this);
  }

  ModuleA moduleA;
  ModuleB moduleB;
  ModuleC moduleC;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're not quite using classes right, please go to this [link for an explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

````js
import ModuleA from './modules/a'
import ModuleB from './modules/b'
import ModuleC from './modules/c'

class Parent {
  constructor(){
    this.moduleA = new ModuleA(this);
    this.moduleB = new ModuleB(this);
    this.moduleC = new ModuleC(this);
  }
}```
````

Comment: I am asking about Dart, not JS